# how to restart a reference to flash as3 movieclip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

i use various movieClips with movieClip buttons in them-all MC's are inserted through code,there is nothing on the stage.
each time the button's eventListener is trigered i call the next function where i add the next movieClip in line and then i want to remove the reference to the MovieClip i used before.

to be more specific i am writing a puzzle game and each time i enter the game,move one of the pieces and press the MovieClip back button,next time i enter the same game i still see the piece where i left it and i want the movieClip to restart to its original position.
what am i doing wrong here?
don't mind the vars the point here is how when i click back at each of the functions i restart the references to what they were when i started the game?
thanks.

```
public function start1()
        {

                  //start screen

            addChild(first1);
            first1.start(button name).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start); 

        }


    public function back1(even:MouseEvent)
{
removeChildAt(numChildren - 1); //want to remove who ever called back1
start1();
}

    public function start(even:MouseEvent)
{
       /choosing num of pieces

       removeChildAt(numChildren - 1); //want to remove first1
       addChild(level);
       level.back.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, back1);
       level.sixpieces.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sixLevel);

}
  //level choosing
    public function sixLevel(even:MouseEvent)
{   
    removeChildAt(numChildren - 1); //want to remove level
     addChild(clevel);
      clevel.back.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, back1);
      clevel.easy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){Slevel=1;six(even);});
      clevel.med.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){Slevel=2;six(even);});
      clevel.hard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){Slevel=3;six(even);});


}

//game itself
    public function six(even:MouseEvent)
{   
    num=6;
    row1=0;
    row2=1;
    row3=2;
    row4=3;

     removeChildAt(numChildren - 1);
      addChild(full1);

      if(Slevel==1)
      {
          full1.time1.visible=false;
          full1.full.visible=true;
        full1.frame1.visible=false;

      }
    else
     if(Slevel==2)
     {
         full1.full.visible=false;
          myTimer = new Timer(1000,60);
     }
     else
     if(Slevel==3)
     {
          full1.full.visible=false;
           myTimer = new Timer(1000,30);
     }
    if(Slevel!=1)
    {
        Slevel=4;

    }
    full1.back.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, back1);
    for(a=0;a<6;a++)
    {
        this.locarrs[3][a].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, Move);
        this.locarrs[3][a].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopMove);
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the original positions and repos on back click or you could create and destroy the movieclips each time. Simply adding again to the display list is not enough since its position is saved on the mc itself.

Comment: thanks.
how do i destroy the movieClip? wont it delete all the initial data i had on it such as original positions?
saving positions is good when you have a six part puzzle but when you 100 it start to get a mess.
i am looking for a general solution that will cover any amount of pieces.

Comment: Yes, destroiyng the object cleans its position. If you want to reuse them, You can create a dictionary. The mc would be the key and an object holding positions the content like: myDictionary[myMC] = {x:initXPos, y:initYPos};

Comment: thanks.
is there anyway to restore the original mc data without writing down each piece location?
this specific mc contains 7 children-6 puzzle pieces and the whole picture each with it's own instance name and in this case it would be rather easy to write down each piece location but once i go to a large number of pieces writing locations down will be kind of a problem. i am looking to restore the pieces original location once the back button is pressed without using location's array

Comment: why dont each mc have its own dictionary holdig references to its children? so each mc would be resposible for its own children and you could automatize the process. 
If you could abstract the mc to its own class make it resposible for its contents.
If you start to create and delete objects, you need to start to REALLY keep an eye on the GC and make sure you clean up everything after each click on the back button. I think the best solution would to save positions in the dictionary on creation and apply them on destroy.